# How do you open a second editor view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a nice high-resolution widescreen monitor, and I'll like to be able to edit files side-by-side in Eclipse (so I can reference one file whilst working in another, for example). I've looked around in the usual menus, but have not figured out how to do this.

Does anyone know if it is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: when files are side-by-side, I would suggest shortcut `ALT+SHIFT+Y` to word wrap lines if screen becomes too small

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Click on the tab of one of the files you want to edit and drag the tab to the edge of the editor frame until you see a vertical line appear in the middle of the editor frame. Then drop the tab there and you have two files to view side-by-side.

Comment: Funny, I tried that, but just did not go far enough to the right. :) Thanks!

Comment: Take note though, you need to have more than one class tab already open, otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 16):

MENU : Window -> New Editor (Side by side) / Ctrl + 8

Comment: Strangely, I don't have the **Window** > **New Editor (Side by side)** menu option, nor does **Ctrl + 8** work. I'm running Eclipse 3.5.2 with Aptana RadRails 2.0.5.

Comment: New function/shortcut for Eclipse Helios (3.6).

Comment: I don't see it in Helios either.  I did read that this is a JBoss plugin feature.  Is there a version of Eclipse JDT that has this built in?

Comment: @glenviewjeff You're right! I didn't realize this function is part of JBoss Tools Plugins.

Answer (score 1):

**I am using Eclipse Helios.**

> RIGHT CLICK ON THE TAB --> MOVE --> EDITOR

**And then just drag it to the Project Explorer side and release the click.**

Automatically you can see the parallel views :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the required files just by [Right Click - >Detach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTLT5.png)