# Xcode - How to view two files side-by-side?

Tags: xcode, eclipse

I'm an experienced Eclipse user and am moving over to Xcode (I have version 9 right now).

**In Xcode, how do I view two source code files side-by-side vertically** (i.e. one file on the left, and another on the right)? In Eclipse, to get a split view window, it's a simple matter of [dragging one tab from the left to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974828/how-do-you-open-a-second-editor-view-in-eclipse). How do I do this in Xcode?

Here is what I mean in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse IDE with side-by-side files]

Comment: Please mark this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617395/8164116 as "ANSWERED"

Answer (score 124, accepted):

### Xcode 11 and above ([thanks for the update, @Uthen!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115855/uthen))

Click on the **Add Editor on Right** button in the top right corner of the editor:

[image: Add Editor on Right button]

To add an editor **to the bottom** instead, **hold down the Option** key while pressing the button, it will change to **Add Editor Below**:

[image: Add Editor Below button]

If you want to **choose a different file to show**, navigate to a different file using the folder buttons above the editor:

[image: Folder buttons]

---

### Xcode 10 and earlier

Simply click on the button in the top right corner with two overlapping circles to access it or navigate to **View/Assistant Editor/Show Assistant editor** (<kbd>⌥⌘^↩</kbd>).

[image: Assistant editor button]

If you want to **choose a different file to show**, click on the button right to the navigation arrows in the right side of the screen and select an option from the context menu. Choose **Manual** to pick any file you want.

[image: Button right to the navigation arrows]

[image: Context menu for picking the file being shown]

If you want to change the layout to horizontal/vertical, navigate to **View/Assistant Editor** and change the view. Here, you can also **add and remove new assistant editors** if display more than two files at the same time.

[image: View/Assistant Editor]

Comment: Thank you. Eclipse has a much more intuitive means for the split view. Why does Xcode use the term "assistant editor"?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 My guess is that Xcode is referring to the supplementary file(s) on the other side as "assistants", as they are being helpers for the main file. I'm not sure though.

Comment: is it removed in xc11 or moved somewhere else ? can't find it...

Comment: Why do i have this option Disabled??

Comment: This was doing my head in mate. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @PeterLapisu there is a "focus this editor" feature which causes the assistant editor feature to become disabled. Tap the "unfocus this editor" button to get out of this mode and enable the assistant editor again.

Comment: Anyone has that "Add Editor on Right" button grayed out and not pressable?

Comment: mine is locked, somehow. are there any method to unlock it?

Comment: If the icon is locked you're probably in focus mode:

View > Editor > Hide Focus

Should reenable it.

Answer (score 51):

A much easier method is to option-click the file you want in the Xcode project view, and it will open in the assistant editor position (typically to the right of the current file). No more tedious searching around with the horrible navigation menu in the assistant!

Comment: That's a good tip, but even that is difficult to find the file. This feature stops me from using XCode as a primary editor.

Comment: @user1386213 It still works in XCode 12.5 for me. Hold the option key down, and click on files in either the project view or the editor tabs and they will open in a new editor view.

Comment: Works fine for me, 12.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 11

```
View > Change Editor Orientation
```

Open the Assistant Editor, then change the orientation as needed:

[image: Change Editor Orientation]

Answer (score 1):

Bonus tip:

If you need to do outlet connection from storyboard to code as prior to xcode 11, select your storyboard view, then click on the "Adjust Editor Options" button at the top right, and choose "Assistant".

[image]