# Unable to use Ctrl+ Click in STS

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using windows 10 laptop and since morning STS IDE ctrl + click is not working and I am unable to open the files on Ctrl+CLick.

Have restarted the machine as well as IDE numerous times still to no avail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974828/how-do-you-open-a-second-editor-view-in-eclipse

Comment: Answer above is  not my problem. My issue is I can't navigate to java methods or class as I am unable to use ctrl +click to navigate

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Maven user settings inside Windows--> Preferences--> User Settings and  was not picking correct settings.xml file required for correct maven build. As a result,STS was unable to identify which type of application it is running. STS was therefore not recognising ctrl+click.
I added the correct settings.xml file and it started working fine.